# ReactJS: Dropdown search results from multiple JSON files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I currently have a search function in my project that should search for items that are in my JSON files.

I currently have a functional component and I've already tried mapping the data from the JSON file.

Here is my code:

```
var _ = require('lodash');

    const getObjectValues = obj => {
        const bes = Object.values(obj).map(ral => {
            if (ral instanceof Object) {
                return getObjectValues(ral);
            }

            return ral;
        });

        return bes;
    }

    const dataJSON = [
                        {value: sample1},
                        {value: sample2}
    ];

    const searched = console.log(_.flattenDeep(getObjectValues({dataJSON})));
```

and this is my search

```
<Form>
     <Search className="searchbar"
             placeholder="Search..."
             onSearch = {??????}
     />
</Form>
```

The search bar should be able to display a dropdown list of the search results.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to create a [**Sample CodeSandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) replicating this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is an [`AutoComplete`](https://ant.design/components/auto-complete/) component not an `Input.Search`:

```js
const dataJSON = [{ value: 'sample1' }, { value: 'sample2' }];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <FlexBox>
      <AutoComplete
        dataSource={dataJSON.map(data => data.value)}
        placeholder="input here"
        onSearch={() => console.log('! onSearch Callback')}
        onSelect={() => console.log('!! onSelect Callback')}
      />
    </FlexBox>
  );
}
```

[image]

[image: Edit Q-57156473-AutoCompleteExample]